# Windows Workflow Foundation editing workflow outside visual studio

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

Is it possible to edit the workflows defined in WWF outside of visual studio so that an end user can edit the business rules without resorting to development team?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can re-host the workflow designer in another application or even a web browser (as an XBAP). You can include the out of the box activities too, even change how they look in your re-hosted workflow designer.